# pyODBC + unixodbc + Db2 for iSeries = UnicodeDecodeError, illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, ibm-midrange, pyodbc

I am able to successfully use pyODBC with SQLAlchemy in my docker container to connect to DB2 for iSeries (version 7.2). It works, but intermittently I'll run a query and get back the following traceback:

```
>>> Groups.query.get(group_id)

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 154, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 550, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 64-65: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

Sometimes this will happen many times in a row and then suddenly stop. It does not always happen with the same set of queries, and I have tried two nearly-identical DB2 servers and gotten the same results.

The 'position 64-65' is always the same for the same query (even though sometimes the query returns correct results).

#### Versions:

- pyodbc: 4.0.26
- unixodbc: 2.3.4-1 (debian)
- SQLAlchemy: 1.3.5
- iAccess driver: `ibm-iaccess-1.1.0.11-1.0`

Comment: Do more digging. You have not mentioned the data-type in Db2 of the impacted column(s). Find a row that causes the exception to be thrown every time. Determine (with HEX()) if there is a data-issue (with respect to the encoding) on the i-series. For impacted rows, eliminate python by querying the row with the i-access  or isql command line to assess the correctness of the result for the impacted row(s).

Comment: The exact same query, returning the exact same result set will throw this error in pyodbc (just not every time). I have not found a repeatable series of steps but of course I'm still looking--makes me think concurrency issue. The data types involved are DECIMAL, VARCHAR, and INTEGER. There are zero characters outside of the 'normal' range (0-255 ordinal values). Column names consist of uppercase letters and underscores only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.

Somewhere along the stack, there is a limit of 30 characters for column name aliases. My guess at this is pyodbc (db2 supports 128-length column names and aliases) and I've [raised an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/582) to track this problem.

When the 30-char limit is surpassed, pyodbc still attempts to decode a string with the original length of the column name, therefore it is attempting to decode garbage data, sometimes resulting in a UnicodeDecodeError (and all other times returning garbage data.

This is specific to column names (so `cursor.keys()` will show the garbage column names).

My workaround is to force SQLAlchemy to truncate column aliases by using a custom dialect.

customdb2.py:

```
from ibm_db_sa.pyodbc import AS400Dialect_pyodbc

class CustomAS400Dialect(AS400Dialect_pyodbc):
    max_identifier_length = 30
registry.register('db2.pyodbc400_custom', 'customdb2', 'CustomAS400Dialect')
```